# Displaying python str values in django templates

Tags: python, html, django-views, django-templates

I trying to display string items from views in a html template.
Not able to get whole words, instead the words get split and each letter appears in a new line when i use the list tag

Example my list contains -
bfast= [ 'Sugarless black tea', 'veggies', 'greek yogurt' ]
lunch = ['Sea Food', 'All Vegetables']

html-

```
 Breakfast:<br>
                {% for item in bfast %}
                      <li>{{ item|safe }}</li>
                {% endfor %}<br>
            <br>
```

output is each letter in a new line

if i remove the list tag -

```
Lunch:<br>
                {% for item in lunch %}
                    {{ item|safe }}
                {% endfor %}<br>
```

output is each letter like below-
Lunch:
[ ' S e a F o o d ' , ' A l l V e g e t a b l e s ' ]

how can get proper word display?

views-

```
def dietplan(request, email_id):
    patient = get_object_or_404(PatientBasicInfo, pk=email_id)
    patientdiet = get_object_or_404(PatientMenu, pk=email_id)

    bfast = patientdiet.breakfast
    lunch = patientdiet.lunch
    snack = patientdiet.snack
    dinner = patientdiet.dinner

    return render(request, 'EDApp/diet.html', {'emailid': email_id,'bfast': bfast, 'lunch': lunch, 'snack': snack, 'dinner': dinner})
```

Comment: Is it a list, or a string, at first slight, it looks like it is a *string* that contains `['Sugar...]` as *content*, not a list that contains strings.

Comment: Sorry its a string- <class 'str'>
L ['Sea Food', 'All Vegetables']. How can i get it to print properly in html ?

Comment: and you do not have access to the original list? Can you please include the relevant details of the view?

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem, updated the views. The values are coming from multiselect choices from a form in the view before ,then stored in the db and being called in this function to display the results

Comment: well it looks like you do not store the values properly, usually such lists are stored as  an extra model related through a `ForeignKey` or a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: i am storing them with a one to one relationship in the models

Comment: but since it is a *list* of things, it thus means that a `patientdiet.luch` can refer to *multiple* things, hence you should make a `PatientLunchItem` with a fk or m2m to `PatientMenu` for example.

Comment: Sorry newbie here! Will try that thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using ast module, changed views to -

```
bfast = ast.literal_eval(patientdiet.breakfast) #patientdiet.breakfast
    lunch = ast.literal_eval(patientdiet.lunch)
    snack = ast.literal_eval(patientdiet.snack)
    dinner = ast.literal_eval(patientdiet.dinner)
```